# Parse data from Pandas HTML list and collect them into DataFrame (or Excel spreadsheet)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have extracted some contents from Outlook email and now have them in an HTML format, Pandas List. I eventually want to create a DataFrame (or Excel spreadsheet) only with the information I want to include.
I'm having trouble parsing the information from the HTML list and storing them in a DataFrame.

For example, I ran followed code to extract ALL data from my emails. I used pd.read_html to view this data.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(16)
messages = inbox.Items

for message in messages:
    print(message.Subject)
    html_str = message.HTMLBody
    try:
        df =  pd.read_html(html_str) 
        print(df)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

And I got something like this as an output:

```
0  Working Timekeeper: 27298 Kate Harris
1                          Date: 11/16/2020
2                         Number Missing: 1,                                                    0
0  DateRequiredWorkedMissingFriday11/06/20208.006...,         0           1         2       3        4
0    Date         NaN  Required  Worked  Missing
1  Friday  11/06/2020      8.00    6.04     1.96
2     NaN         NaN       NaN    6.04     1.96,                                           0
0  Working Timekeeper: 83486 Chris Wolfe
1                          Date: 11/16/2020
2                         Number Missing: 6,                                                    0
0  DateRequiredWorkedMissingFriday11/06/20208.006...,            0           1         2       3        4
0       Date         NaN  Required  Worked  Missing
1     Friday  11/06/2020      8.00    6.04     1.96
2     Monday  11/09/2020      8.00    0.00     8.00
3    Tuesday  11/10/2020      8.00    0.00     8.00
4  Wednesday  11/11/2020      8.00    0.00     8.00
5   Thursday  11/12/2020      8.00    0.00     8.00
6     Friday  11/13/2020      8.00    0.00     8.00
7        NaN         NaN       NaN    6.04    41.96,                                            0
```

What I want as my final output needs only two types of information: Name of each Timekeeper and the following date/time tables. For example, I want to parse the current list and make a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 Name          Weekday          Date       Required  Worked  Missing
 Kate Harris   Friday       11/06/2020        8.00    6.04     1.96
```

Is there any way to do this in Python? Or is it out of scope? I'm new to Python and not sure if it's possible. I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: You can slice the dataframe to get the desired columns. For ex. a df has 3 columns a,b  and c and you want a dataframe of a and b, just do df = df[["a", "b"]] or df.loc[:, ["a","b"]]

Comment: The thing is I currently have my data in a list format and I can't really  parse or convert them into any other format

Comment: pd.read_html() returns list of dataframes. To get a dataframe, simply do df[0] when you read from html

Comment: Thanks @Harsh, Now I understand the format. Then, can I extract a certain string from a certain row in each data frame if the data frame contains a certain string and collect them in a list? For example, can i do something like: for i in range(len(df)): if the first row of each data frame contains " working Timekeeper,  extract the name (e.g. Katy Harris) and compile them in a separate list?

Comment: You seem confused about dataframes and the methods. I would ask you to first go through some examples online and maybe read the docs. I will try and answer this question in the answers

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_html()` according to the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns a list of dataframes.
Now you can access each of the dataframe by looping through the list. For example:

```
ls_df = pd.read_html(my_html_string)
for df in ls_df:
    '''df is the dataframe object. You can perform all 
    the operations defined for a dataframe by pandas. For example, if you want list of 
    rows from dataframe with specific values for specific column, 
    you can simply do:'''
   
    all_values = df.loc[df["columnname"] == somevalue, ]
```

`df.loc[]` takes two `args`, the first `arg` slices the rows and second one gives columns. So in the above code, entering nothing after somevalue, simply means I want all columns from the dataframe. You can slice it using
`df.loc[df["colname"] == somevalue, ["list of cols"]]` to get subset of columns.

I provided the code snippet to access certain rows because you wanted to extract a certain string from certain row if `df` had that string. So you can use the above code and replace all the variables and placeholders according to your need.

Cheers!